# Hibernate incorrectly formatting oracle sql

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am migrating to hibernate 4.1 and also adding support for oracle 11g. The migration to 4.1 appears to have gone ok with the mysql setup and I am debugging oracle specific problems. I have an issue where oracle complains with

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

I should mention this setup is also using c3p0 and ehcache.

The query that causes this exception is:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - 

select
    dp.id as id168_,
    dp.Description as Descript2_168_,
    dp.name as name168_,
    case 
        when dp1_.id is not null then 1 
        when dp2_.id is not null then 2 
        when dp.id is not null then 0 
    end as clazz_ 
from
    .tableA dp 
left outer join
    .tableB dp1_ 
        on dp.id=dp1_.id 
left outer join
    .tableC dp2_ 
        on dp.id=dp2_.id
```

I tried this query in SQL Developer and it failed. The problem appears to be with the '.' on the table names. If I remove this or put the db user/schema before the query is good.

Is there a setting to turn this notation off?
Have I not provided a property that is needed?

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="myUser"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="myPassword"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin://@192.168.X.X:1521:oracledb"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value=""/>

        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="public"/>

        <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>

        <!-- cache configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>

        <!-- pool configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="17" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="3600" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>

    </properties>
```

Comment: I have a hunch its something to do with the hibernate.default_schema property but I havent explored this fully yet

Comment: Is your database named 'public'? Because default_schema is the database name for oracle..

Comment: my schema was the same as the user, I have corrected this and it seems to have allowed the artefact to deploy.

Comment: Can you show us the mapping file and the HQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was with

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="public"/>
```

This value needs to match the schema that you have created.

ctapobep's comment helped identify  this problem.